# add element to the array on the nearest free place

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

Task is: Method AddRectangle that adds a rectangle of type Rectangle to the array on the nearest free place and returning true, or returning false, if there is no free space in the array

```
 public class ArrayRectangles
{
    private Rectangle[] rectangle_array;
    public ArrayRectangles(int n)
    {
        Rectangle[] rectangle = new Rectangle[n];

    }
    public ArrayRectangles(Rectangle[] rectangle)
    {
        rectangle_array = rectangle;
    }
    public bool AddRectangle(Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        bool empty = true;
        //var openArray = 0;
        //for (int i = 0; i < rectangle_array.Length; i++)
        //{
        //    if (rectangle_array[i] == null)
        //    {
        //        rectangle_array[i] = rectangle;
        //        empty = true;

        //    }
        //}
        return empty;
    }
```

I don't know how to deal with this method AddRectangle
please, help!!!

Comment: Other than starting with `bool empty = false;` how does the code not behave the way you expected?

Comment: what do you mean? what is the problem here?

Comment: In the commented code you need to add a _break_ inside the if to exit the for loop when you find an empty slot. And the boolean _empty_ should start with false.

Comment: What means "on the nearest free place"? Is that array somehow ordered?

Comment: And there is another error (I would close this question as a typos collection). In the constructor for the _ArrayRectangles_ class you need to initialize the internal _rectangle_array_ not an unused local variable called _rectangle_

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code actually almost working.
Just return `true` when you find empty spot, and return `false` if the iteration is over without return:

```
public bool AddRectangle(Rectangle rectangle)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rectangle_array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (rectangle_array[i] == null)
        {
            rectangle_array[i] = rectangle;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the **AddRectangle** function will always return true as the value of *empty* is never false. Also, the given rectangle will be stored in all the empty spaces in the array, which I'm sure is not the desired scenario.

Hence, you need to initialize the empty variable to false, considering that initially, there is no empty space. And then, as soon as you find one, just store the rectangle there, set empty to true, and break the loop.

```java
public class ArrayRectangles
{
    private Rectangle[] rectangle_array;
    public ArrayRectangles(int n)
    {
        Rectangle[] rectangle = new Rectangle[n];

    }
    public ArrayRectangles(Rectangle[] rectangle)
    {
        rectangle_array = rectangle;
    }
    public bool AddRectangle(Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        bool empty = false;
        var openArray = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rectangle_array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (rectangle_array[i] == null)
            {
                rectangle_array[i] = rectangle;
                empty = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return empty;
    }
```

Comment: You dont need the empty flag. Instead of `empty=true;break;` just `return true;` and then instead of `return empty` at the end of the function `return false`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.FindIndex() instead of a for loop.

```
public bool AddRectangle(Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        var firstEmptyIndex = Array.FindIndex(rectangle_array, i => i == null);

        if(firstEmptyIndex == -1)
            return false;

        rectangle_array[firstEmptyIndex] = rectangle;

        return true;
    }
```